# Get WordPress post data for use in an iPhone app

Tags: wordpress

We're moving a website to WordPress, and I need to modify our iPhone app to get data from the new site. Currently it gets neatly structured data out of our database, but now all data will be stored in the text of WordPress posts and formatted by WP plugins. I know very little about WordPress.

Any suggestions for a good way to get that data to the app?

Is there an easy way to get the raw text of a post?

I thought there would be a plugin for that but I haven't been able to turn anything up. And I'd like to avoid just parsing the page HTML for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the MySQL database and know your tables and fields (in Wordpress' MySQL DB) then you could simply pull the data with AJAX or PHP calls.

Comment: Yeah pretty much what I ended up doing- pulling the data with PHP WP templating functions.